# SwiftUI 4.0 how to know if ShareLink has been shared successfully

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am now working with the new SwiftUI 4.0 and using the new ShareLink feature . How can I know if a link or text has been shared successfully, any suggestions would be great ? I have a simple ShareLink like this

```
          ShareLink(item: InviteMessage) {
                    Text("Test Share")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                 }
```

before in SwiftUI 3.0 I would use this code

```
                .background(SharingViewController(isPresenting: $InviteOthers) {
                    let message = "Share Me"
                    let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message], applicationActivities: nil)
                    av.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity, success, items, error) in

                        if success {
                            // shared successfully update count
                        }
                       }
                       
                    return av
                })
```

Comment: Hi there, I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Seems to be no posible since de docs for this type doesn't return anything, and the signature for the method doesn't accept any closure, to handle states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a ShareLink in a sheet that was presented that I couldn't make disappear. But I changed it to a Menu and the Menu automatically disappears when the sharing is successful.

```
Menu {
    ShareLink(item: "The text to share") {
        Label("Text", systemImage: "text.alignleft")
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't seem possible to know if the content has been shared successfully, but you can at least detect if the link has been clicked with the `simultaneousGesture` modifier (`onTapGesture` doesn't work on ShareLink):

```
ShareLink(){}
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded() {
    print("clicked") 
})
```

Comment: yeah, this seems like one of the best purely swiftUI compromised solutions so far

Comment: not working on macOS

Comment: not working on iOS, too

Comment: @VilémKurz on iOS, simple code like printing works for me. But more complicated code doesn't. To make it work, I execute the code after a short a delay: .simultaneousGesture(
            TapGesture().onEnded() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    // do your stuff 
                }
            }
        )

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure its posible, but you definitely can add tokens to the url, and track when people open it. But as far as if it actually sent, i can’t help.